# Add swipe to switch between fragments

Tags: android, swipe, android-tabs

I want to add swipe to this activity to switch between its fragments, right now the app is detecting the movement. The tab switching should be made by the functions SwipeLeft and SwipeRight, but I don't know how to do it. Can someone please explain me how to do it please?

```
public class Cantina extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    Tab tabA = actionBar.newTab();
    tabA.setText("seg");
    tabA.setTabListener(new TabListener<MyFragmentA>(this, "seg", MyFragmentA.class));
    actionBar.addTab(tabA);

    ... 3 tabs

    Tab tabE = actionBar.newTab();
    tabE.setText("sex");
    tabE.setTabListener(new TabListener<MyFragmentE>(this, "sex", MyFragmentE.class));
    actionBar.addTab(tabE);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        int savedIndex = savedInstanceState.getInt("SAVED_INDEX");
        getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(savedIndex);
    }

}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("SAVED_INDEX", getActionBar().getSelectedNavigationIndex());
}

public static class TabListener<T extends Fragment> 
    implements ActionBar.TabListener{

    private final Activity myActivity;
    private final String myTag;
    private final Class<T> myClass;

    public TabListener(Activity activity, String tag, Class<T> cls) {
        myActivity = activity;
        myTag = tag;
        myClass = cls;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

        Fragment myFragment = myActivity.getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(myTag);

        // Check if the fragment is already initialized
        if (myFragment == null) {
            // If not, instantiate and add it to the activity
            myFragment = Fragment.instantiate(myActivity, myClass.getName());
            ft.add(android.R.id.content, myFragment, myTag);
        } else {
            // If it exists, simply attach it in order to show it
            ft.attach(myFragment);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

        Fragment myFragment = myActivity.getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(myTag);

        if (myFragment != null) {
            // Detach the fragment, because another one is being attached
            ft.detach(myFragment);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
public void SwipeRight(){
    Toast.makeText(this, "RIGHT", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
}

private void SwipeLeft(){
    Toast.makeText(this, "LEFT", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
}
SimpleOnGestureListener simpleOnGestureListener 
= new SimpleOnGestureListener(){

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
            float velocityY) {

        float sensitvity = 50;
        if((e1.getX() - e2.getX()) > sensitvity){
            SwipeLeft();
        }else if((e2.getX() - e1.getX()) > sensitvity){
            SwipeRight();
        }

        return true;
    }

};

GestureDetector gestureDetector
= new GestureDetector(simpleOnGestureListener);
```

}

Comment: You can use ViewPager see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html

Comment: use ViewPager you need

Answer (score 1):

If it fits with your requirement then you can go for it. Official guide from Android Developers.

[Swipe View with Tabs](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html)